# R - what to use as interface for web service in c#?

Tags: c#, xml, r

I'm writing R code that processes XML, and my dev guy needs to be able to send the R server code and some XML and get some new XML back as a response within his c# application.

We've been looking at Rserve with the RServeCLI integration however it's looking like the XML package functionality won't work.  I have an open question for R.Net asking if XML classes can be used.

Does anyone have any recommendations on how best to interface R with c# in such a way that the following script could be executed...

```
library(XML)
input<-"<blah> a</blah>"
input.xml<-xmlInternalTreeParse(input)
myval<-xpathSApply(input.xml, '//blah', xmlValue)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end we've been using `Rapache` which was pretty easy to install and configure.  It allows the hosting of the XML processing code and presenting the response very easily.

For more details on Rapache, check out the [manual](http://rapache.net/)